# Docutils difference between text and rawsource in nodes.Text?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

When creating new nodes such as `nodes.title`, one needs to provide two strings:

1. `rawsource`
2. `text`

Often I see this:

```
nodes.title('foobar', 'foobar', ids=[id])
```

Or sometime...

```
nodes.target('', '')
```

I don't understand why this repetition, and why it is useful to have or not have twice the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The "rawsource" attribute of doctree nodes is intended for diagnostic purposes.
It allows to check which rST source part led to the cration of a specific node.
Production code should not rely on it and leaving it empty should not change the output.

Up to Docutils 0.16, escape characters were removed in the "text" attribute during rST parsing. This could lead to different "text" and "rawsource" even in `nodes.Text` elements.

Since 0.16, `nodes.Text.rawsource` is optional, only kept for backwards compatibility, deprecated since Docutils 0.18, and will be removed in Docutils 2.0.

Note, that the other nodes (inheriting from `nodes.Element`) keep the "rawsource" attribute.